How to fetch YouTube tags using search YouTube VideoId API call?
I need to fetch tags from snippet using YouTube API VideoId API.
Refer the below response and log. I don't find tags in the response. So it prints tags as empty. How can I fetch tags information from the VideoSnippet?
Sample code:
public static void printVideo(int index, @NonNull Video video) {
        VideoSnippet snippet = video.getSnippet();
       log.trace("Video[" + index + "] Tags = {}", snippet.getTags());
}

Test log:
    youtube.log:[Test worker] TRACE com.ct.youtube.util.YouTubeUtil - Video[0] Tags = null

Sample Response:
{
  "contentDetails": {
    "duration": "PT5M28S"
  },
  "snippet": {
    "channelId": "UCVfwlh9XpX2Y_tQfjeln9QA",
    "channelTitle": "BibleProject",
    "description": "The wisest king of Israel, King Solomon, is associated with three books of the Bible: Proverbs, Ecclesiastes, and the Song of Songs. Each book offers a unique perspective on how humans can rule with wisdom and the fear of the Lord. In this video, we briefly explore how the message of each book fits into the overall story of the Bible.\n\n#Solomon #Proverbs #Wisdom",
    "publishedAt": "2019-06-27T22:09:15.000Z",
    "thumbnails": {
      "default": {
        "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/WJgt1vRkPbI/default.jpg"
      }
    },
    "title": "The Books of Solomon"
  },
  "statistics": {
    "commentCount": "1839",
    "favoriteCount": "0",
    "likeCount": "37779",
    "viewCount": "1213094"
  }
}


https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=WJgt1vRkPbI&key=KEY returns correctly tags.

Make sure that your project in the Google Cloud Console has the correct permissions and that the YouTube Data API v3 is enabled.
import com.google.api.services.youtube.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class YouTubeVideoFetcher {
    private static final String API_KEY = "YOUR_API_KEY";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        YouTube youtubeService = new YouTube.Builder(
            new com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport(),
            new com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory(),
            request -> {}
        ).setApplicationName("youtube-tags-fetcher").build();

        YouTube.Videos.List request = youtubeService.videos()
            .list("snippet")
            .setId("YOUR_VIDEO_ID") // Replace with the actual video ID
            .setKey(API_KEY);
        VideoListResponse response = request.execute();

        List<Video> videos = response.getItems();
        if (!videos.isEmpty()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < videos.size(); i++) {
                VideoSnippet snippet = videos.get(i).getSnippet();
                List<String> tags = snippet.getTags();
                System.out.println("Video[" + i + "] Tags = " + (tags != null ? tags : "No tags found"));
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("No videos found for the given ID.");
        }
    }
}

